# Cut smaller polygons out of larger ones in using R/sf

Tags: r, sf, differences

I've got a set of polygons containing overlapping geographical levels, both regions and cities. This is a simplified example:

[image: My two overlapping polygons]

I want to cut the cities out of the regions. So in the example above, I want to turn the red area in to a donut. I know I can use `st_difference()` to do it for individual pairs of polygons. But is there a way to automatically cut all the smaller areas out of the larger areas they overlap with?

Here's my example data:

```r
library(sf)

example = structure(
  list(
    id = 1:2,
    geometry = structure(
      list(structure(
        list(structure(c(
          0,
          0, 5, 5, 0, 0, 5, 5, 0, 0
        ), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY",
                                         "POLYGON", "sfg")
      ), structure(
        list(structure(c(
          3, 3, 4, 4, 3,
          3, 4, 4, 3, 3
        ), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON",
                                         "sfg")
      )),
      class = c("sfc_POLYGON", "sfc"),
      precision = 0,
      bbox = structure(c(
        xmin = 0,
        ymin = 0,
        xmax = 5,
        ymax = 5
      ), class = "bbox"),
      crs = structure(list(input = NA_character_, wkt = NA_character_), class = "crs"),
      n_empty = 0L
    )
  ),
  row.names = 1:2,
  class = c("sf", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),
  sf_column = "geometry"
)
#> Simple feature collection with 2 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 5 ymax: 5
#> CRS:           NA
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>      id                    geometry
#> * <int>                   <POLYGON>
#> 1     1 ((0 0, 0 5, 5 5, 5 0, 0 0))
#> 2     2 ((3 3, 3 4, 4 4, 4 3, 3 3))
```

Comment: There's the `st_overlaps` function which will tell you if two features overlap... Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

First we should separate cities from regions, as you state they are in the same set of polygons, we can achieve that filtering with `st_contains_properly` which will give us the larger polygons, and then filter out this `id` list from the original set; `st_combine` is an important part here, otherwise it will make a 1x1 comparison and polygons will not be `clipped`.

```r
larger_pols = example |> st_filter(example, .predicate = st_contains_properly)
smaller_pols = example |> filter(!id %in% larger_pols$id )

st_difference(st_combine(larger_pols), st_combine(smaller_pols)) |> plot()
```

[image]